# Using GROUP_CONCAT on multiple fields

Tags: mysql

Here's a picture of my database structure:

[image: Observation recording - database structure]

With help from users on here I've managed to put together quite a complex SQL statement using `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT
     t1.Name AS Teacher_Name,
     t2.Name AS Observer_Name,
     o.Datetime AS Datetime,
     o.Type AS Type,
     o.Year_Group AS Year_Group,
     o.Class_Name AS Class_Name,
     c.Title AS Course_Name,
     GROUP_CONCAT(l.Title) AS Focus,
     o.Achievement_Grade AS Achievement_Grade,
     o.Behaviour_Grade AS Behaviour_Grade,
     o.Teaching_Grade AS Teaching_Grade,
     GROUP_CONCAT(cl1.Title) AS Positive,
     GROUP_CONCAT(cl2.title) AS Development,
     o.Notes AS Notes
FROM observations o
LEFT JOIN teachers t1 
    ON o.Teacher_ID = t1.Teacher_ID
LEFT JOIN teachers t2 
    ON o.Observer_ID = t2.Teacher_ID
LEFT JOIN courses c 
    ON o.Course_ID = c.Course_ID
LEFT JOIN  foci f
    ON o.ID = f.Observation_ID
LEFT JOIN focus_labels l
    on f.focus_id = l.id
LEFT JOIN  criteria c1
    ON o.ID = c1.Observation_ID
LEFT JOIN criteria_labels cl1
    on c1.Criteria_ID = cl1.ID AND c1.Type = 'P'
LEFT JOIN  criteria c2
    ON o.ID = c2.Observation_ID AND c2.Type = 'D'
LEFT JOIN criteria_labels cl2
    on c2.Criteria_ID = cl2.ID
GROUP BY o.id
ORDER BY `Datetime` DESC";
```

This appears to work OK, apart from the fact that `Focus`, `Positive` and `Development` are each repeated depending on the field that has the highest number of concatenations in.

For example, if `Positive` has `Pace,Progress,Attainment` but `Focus` is only `Appraisal`, it'll be repeated three times (`Appraisal,Appraisal,Appraisal`).

[image: Observation Recording - Complex join structure]

I've looked this up and I think it could be because I need to `GROUP` each of these `GROUP_CONCAT JOINs`. However, I have no idea how to go about this.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) has DISTINCT attribute that can be applied to remove duplicates.

```
SELECT
     t1.Name AS Teacher_Name,
     t2.Name AS Observer_Name,
     o.Datetime AS Datetime,
     o.Type AS Type,
     o.Year_Group AS Year_Group,
     o.Class_Name AS Class_Name,
     c.Title AS Course_Name,
     GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT l.Title) AS Focus,
     o.Achievement_Grade AS Achievement_Grade,
     o.Behaviour_Grade AS Behaviour_Grade,
     o.Teaching_Grade AS Teaching_Grade,
     GROUP_CONCAT(cl1.Title) AS Positive,
     GROUP_CONCAT(cl2.title) AS Development,
     o.Notes AS Notes
FROM observations o
LEFT JOIN teachers t1 
    ON o.Teacher_ID = t1.Teacher_ID
LEFT JOIN teachers t2 
    ON o.Observer_ID = t2.Teacher_ID
LEFT JOIN courses c 
    ON o.Course_ID = c.Course_ID
LEFT JOIN  foci f
    ON o.ID = f.Observation_ID
LEFT JOIN focus_labels l
    on f.focus_id = l.id
LEFT JOIN  criteria c1
    ON o.ID = c1.Observation_ID
LEFT JOIN criteria_labels cl1
    on c1.Criteria_ID = cl1.ID AND c1.Type = 'P'
LEFT JOIN  criteria c2
    ON o.ID = c2.Observation_ID AND c2.Type = 'D'
LEFT JOIN criteria_labels cl2
    on c2.Criteria_ID = cl2.ID
GROUP BY o.id
ORDER BY `Datetime` DESC";
```